# Trying to send a form to a view, but cant grab the correct 'post_id' that the view requires.

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a form created in comments/forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import Comment

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('body',)
```

this form has a template in comments/comment_form.html:

```
<h2>this is the comment form</h2>
<form class="post-form" method="post" action="{% url 'comments:create' post.id %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
```

as you can see, I am sending this form to comments:create. this is the view for handling the form:

```
def create(request, post_id):
    post =  get_object_or_404(Post, pk= post_id)
    group = post.group



     if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.author = request.user
            comment.post = post
            comment.pub_date = timezone.now()
            comment.save()
            return redirect('/groups/' + str(group.id))

    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'comments/comment_form.html', {'form':form})
```

The issue is that I'm rendering the form on the 'groups/detail.html':

```
{% include "comments/comment_form.html" %}
```

the problem is that this form obviously requires a post_id because the comment belongs to a post. THE ISSUE IS THAT I DONT HAVE ACCESS TO AN INDIVIDUAL POST ON THE GROUPS DETAIL PAGE, OR I AT LEAST DONT KNOW HOW TO ACCESS AN INDIVIDUAL POST. below is the group detail view:

```
def detail(request, group_id):
    group = get_object_or_404(Group, pk= group_id)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(group__id = group_id)
    post = posts.objects.first()


    form = CommentForm(request.POST)

    return render(request, 'groups/detail.html', {'group': group, 'posts':posts, 'post':post, 'form':form})
```

as you can see, I simply grabbed the first post (for testing purposes) even though thats not what I want. I want the to grab the post that the comment was made for. I cannot get it from the url because it doesnt make sense to include a post_id for the group detail page. here is the url for the groups detail page:

```
app_name = 'groups'

urlpatterns = [

    path('<int:group_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),

]
```

I simply want to know if there is a way to grab the individual post on the group detail page, so that I can submit the form to the comments:create view, which handles it correctly. the comments create view requires a post_id:

```
def create(request, post_id):
    post =  get_object_or_404(Post, pk= post_id)
    group = post.group

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.author = request.user
            comment.post = post
            comment.pub_date = timezone.now()
            comment.save()
            return redirect('/groups/' + str(group.id))

    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'comments/comment_form.html', {'form':form})
```

in short, I need to instantiate a variable in the group detail view so that I can pass it into the form, so it can give it to the comments create view. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would be easy to do, but a little less user friendly, is to have a link under each post which redirects to a comment page. Then on the comment page you will have access to the post ID because you can obtain it through the URL.

This would be your html for the link to the comment form under each post:

```
postpage.html

{% for i in post %}
    {{ i.post }}
    <a href="/posts/{{i.pk}}">Comment on this Post!</a>
{% endfor %}
```

...then redirects to your comment form page...

Comment form URL will look like this = .../posts/[pk]

```
<h2>this is the comment form</h2>
<form class="post-form" method="post" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
```

Make sure your URL pattern accepts a PK.

Then in your view you will have access to the pk of the post and can assign that to the comment.

I will say that there are definitely more user friendly ways of doing this (such as a pop up modal to write a comment so you don't have to leave the page) which would probably include some sort of combination of formsets and javascript/ajax.